# Sorting rows in a Shiny Datatable column

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dFramex <<- data.frame(Name = c('10: Dilbert', '5: Alice', '3: Wally', '24: Ashok', '34: Dogbert'),
                       Motivation = c(62, 73, 3, 99, 52))

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "my_data_table")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  values <- reactiveValues(check = '')
  observe({
    values$df <- dFramex

  })
  

  output$my_data_table <-  DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable({
    dFrame1 <-values$df
    dFrame1
  }, editable=TRUE, escape = FALSE,)
  }, server = FALSE, plugins = 'num', options = list(dom = 't',
                                                            columnDefs = list(list(type = 'num', targets = 1))))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am having issue sorting the Name column in this table, currently the Name column gets sorted as when I am trying to sort the table in an ascending order:

10: Dilbert
24: Ashok
34: Dogbert
3: Wally
5: Alice

I want it to be sorted as:

3: Wally
5: Alice
10: Dilbert
24: Ashok
34: Dogbert

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your names are prepended with some kind of numerics which are regarded as part of the string. Therefore the order looks quite weird at first glance: 10 > 24 > 34 > 3 > 5 (> 666 > 7 > 88888888 > 9 and so on).

I just learned there is a way to handle these strings as numerics anyway using `stringr` being able to recreate your desired output:

```r
dFramex[["Name"]] |> stringr::str_sort(numeric = TRUE)
#> [1] "3: Wally"    "5: Alice"    "10: Dilbert" "24: Ashok"   "34: Dogbert"
```

The major downside of this is, you need to reorder your `Motivation` column in the same way to preserve the relations, otherwise Wally has suddenly a value of 62, etc. To achieve this, you can make use of `match`:

```r
# Reorder the vector of characters pretending to handle numerics and match
# these with the original vector to get the indices.
ind <- match(dFramex[["Name"]] |> 
               stringr::str_sort(numeric = TRUE), dFramex[["Name"]])

# Resort your data frame
dFramex <- dFramex[ind, ]

# Inspect. Seems legit.
dFramex
#>          Name Motivation
#> 3    3: Wally          3
#> 2    5: Alice         73
#> 1 10: Dilbert         62
#> 4   24: Ashok         99
#> 5 34: Dogbert         52
```

Comment: I cannot split them up as the data I am working with is set like that but needs to be ordered through the numbers assigned to the beginning of the string. I can't actually break them apart.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I think I might have found a way, see edited post.